# I am working on a checkers game in Java and can't seem to draw pieces on the board

Tags: java, jframe

BoardView.java

```
package checkers.views;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class BoardView extends JPanel{
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        g.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        g.fillRect(100, 100, 400, 400); 
        for(int i = 100; i <= 400; i+=100){ 
            for(int j = 100; j <= 400; j+=100){ 
                g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
                g.fillRect(i, j, 50, 50); 
                } 
            }
        for(int i = 150; i <= 450; i+=100){ 
            for(int j = 150; j <= 450; j+=100){ 
                g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
                g.fillRect(i, j, 50, 50); 
                } 
            }

        } 
}
```

PiecesView.java

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import checkers.models.*;
import checkers.utilities.*;
import checkers.business_logic.*;


public class PieceView extends JPanel{
    public void paint(Graphics g, Board checkersBoard ){
        for (int row = 0; row < 8; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < 8; col++) {
               int color = checkersBoard.piecesGrid[row][col].getColor();
               if(color == ConstantsHolder.RED){
                  g.setColor(Color.RED);
                  g.fillOval(col, row, 60, 60);
               }
               else if(color == ConstantsHolder.BLACK){
                   g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                   g.fillOval(col, row, 60, 60);
               }

            }

        }
    }
}
```

BoardViewDrawer.java

```
import checkers.utilities.*;
import checkers.models.*;
import checkers.views.*;
import checkers.business_logic.*;

public class BoardViewDrawer {

  public static void drawBoard(){

  JFrame Board = new JFrame(); 
    Board.setSize(600,600); 
    Board.getContentPane().add(new BoardView()); 
    Board.setLocationRelativeTo(null); 
    Board.setBackground(Color.BLACK); 
    Board.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
    Board.setVisible(true);
    Board.setTitle("Checkers Palooza");
    Board.setLayout(new GridLayout(8,8));
    Board.getContentPane().add(new PieceView());
```

}

I think this all makes sense but I'm unsure as to what I am doing incorrectly here. I am using the logic of my board to try and set the pieces based on that. If anyone has any insight or just sees what I am doing that is stupid help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where are you calling your paint method in ```PieceView``` ? I don't see it here.

Comment: I'm not I was trying to do it the same way as I did the board.

Comment: For the board it works because you're overriding a super class method, but for the pieceview, the method signature is wrong, so the method never gets called. You can't have ```checkersBoard``` as an argument. Tip: to make sure you're overriding a method, you should use the ```@Override``` annotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `paint` method in `PieceView` never gets called, because it doesn't correctly override the `paint` method. This needs to have the signature of:

```
public void paint(Graphics g);
```

Like in the `BoardView` class.

If you want to use `checkersBoard` in the paint method, you could pass it to the constructor and save it for when you're painting:

```
public class PieceView extends JPanel{

    private Board checkersBoard;

    public PieceView(Board checkersBoard) {
        this.checkersBoard = checkersBoard;
    }

    @Override // makes sure you're overriding
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        // paint code here
    }

    ...
}
```

With that you are free to use `checkersBoard` in the `paint` method.

Comment: The only thing with that is my checkerboard data is coming from a different class. is there a way I can handle that?

Comment: @JacobBrauchler Yes, but I can't give you a clear-cut code answer to that. From the looks of it, that would require some re-organization. I would advice you make the checkerboard first and then pass it down to the place where you make your pieceview, so you can pass it to the constructor.